# Shell command 'ls' in Android fails: Syntax error: “(” unexpected

Tags: android, bash, shell, adb, recovery

While I was testing my program in Android, my program crashed.
After that, simple commands like 'ls', 'ps', 'grep', 'chmod' stopped working, and are throwing an exception: syntax error: '(' unexpected.
Some do work, like 'pwd', 'stat' or 'cd'.
For example:

```
@android:/ #  ls -l /bin/sh
 ls -l /bin/sh
/system/bin/ls[1]: syntax error: '(' unexpected

@android:/system/bin # ps | grep a
ps | grep a
/system/bin/ps[1]: syntax error: '(' unexpected
/system/bin/grep[1]: syntax error: '(' unexpected
@android:/ # pwd
pwd
/
```

I tried reboot and re-enter the developer option.
Also tried to do factory data reset.
it doesn't work.
Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Does `ls` without any parameters work?

Comment: you've asked 9 questions but not picked one of them as solving your problems.  I know at least one has, b/c you thanked the person :(

["What should I do when someone answers my question?"][1]
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize I needed to do that. Doing it now. @SaintHax

Comment: Did you trying reinstalling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update or install new ROM.
I had such case with cyanogen ROM. Update CM by settings->About->CyanogenMod update

Comment: thank  you. This is the only thing that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your bash seems broke, reinstall.

your bash

```
@android:/ #  ls -l /bin/sh
 ls -l /bin/sh
/system/bin/ls[1]: syntax error: '(' unexpected
```

to get the error in bash normally.

```
$ ls -l (/bin/sh)
/bin/ls: syntax error: '(' unexpected
```

edited out the offtopic part

Comment: since the whole toolbox is not working, I can't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash
```

choose NO